# Calculate 3 points of intersection

Tags: functions

I have a propably quite basic problem, but school is a long time ago and I can't find a way to solve this. 
I have the two asymptotic curves through the origin 
\begin{equation}
f(x)=20.344\cdot\left(1-\mathrm{e}^{-\mathrm{e}^{-2.583} \cdot x}\right)
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
g(x)=\left(20.344\cdot\left(0.779\cdot\left(1-\mathrm{e}^{-\mathrm{e}^{-1.233} \cdot x}\right)\right)\right) \cdot\left(1-\mathrm{e}^{-\mathrm{e}^{-0.744} \cdot x}\right).
\end{equation}

According to a calculator, they have the three points of intersection (0|0), (0.969|1.436) and (19.797|15.787). Compared to the vizualisation of the curves they are correct. I need the calculation path and the calculator is neither presenting this nor telling the way he used. So I worked the below presented path, but I can't find a method to calculate these three points. The pq formula gives me a wrong result and polynomial division is not applicable. Can someone please tell me how to get to the results?

Thank you very much ahead!

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
&f(x)=g(x)\\
&20.344\cdot\left(1-\mathrm{e}^{-\mathrm{e}^{-2.583} \cdot x}\right)=\left(20.344\cdot\left(0.779\cdot\left(1-\mathrm{e}^{-\mathrm{e}^{-1.233} \cdot x}\right)\right)\right) \cdot\left(1-\mathrm{e}^{-\mathrm{e}^{-0.744} \cdot x}\right)\\
&20.344\cdot\left(1-\mathrm{e}^{-0.076 \mathrm{x}}\right)=\left(20.344\cdot\left(0.779\cdot\left(1-\mathrm{e}^{-\mathrm{e}^{-1.233} \cdot x}\right)\right)\right) \cdot\left(1-\mathrm{e}^{-\mathrm{e}^{-0.744} \cdot x}\right)\\
&-20.344 \cdot e^{-0.076 x}+20.344=\left(20.344\cdot\left(0.779\cdot\left(1-\mathrm{e}^{-\mathrm{e}^{-1.233} \cdot x}\right)\right)\right) \cdot\left(1-\mathrm{e}^{-\mathrm{e}^{-0.744} \cdot x}\right)\\
&-20.344 \cdot e^{-0.076 x}+20.344=\left(20.344\cdot\left(0.779\cdot\left(1-e^{-0.291 x}\right)\right)\right) \cdot\left(1-\mathrm{e}^{-\mathrm{e}^{-0.744} \cdot x}\right)\\
&-20.344 \cdot e^{-0.076 x}+20.344=\left(20.344\cdot\left(-0.779 \cdot e^{-0.291 x}+0.779\right)\right) \cdot\left(1-\mathrm{e}^{-\mathrm{e}^{-0.744} \cdot x}\right)\\
&-20.344 \cdot \mathrm{e}^{-0.076 \mathrm{x}}+20.344=\left(-15.838 \cdot \mathrm{e}^{-0.291 x}+15.838\right) \cdot\left(1-\mathrm{e}^{-\mathrm{e}^{-0.744} \cdot x}\right)\\
&-20.344 \cdot \mathrm{e}^{-0.076 x}+20.344=\left(-15.838 \cdot \mathrm{e}^{-0.291 x}+15.838\right) \cdot\left(1-\mathrm{e}^{-0.475 x}\right)\\
&-20.344 \cdot e^{-0.076 x}+20.344=15.838 \cdot e^{-0.291 x} \cdot e^{-0.475 x}-15.838 \cdot e^{-0.291 x}-15.838 \cdot e^{-0.475 x}+15.838\\
&-20.344 \cdot \mathrm{e}^{-0.076 x}-15.838 \cdot \mathrm{e}^{-0.291 x} \cdot \mathrm{e}^{-0.475 x} \cdot \mathrm{e}^{-0.475 x} \cdot \mathrm{e}^{-0.475 x} \cdot \mathrm{e}^{-0.475 x} \cdot \mathrm{e}^{-0.475 x} \cdot \mathrm{e}^{-0.475 x} \cdot \mathrm{e}^{-0.475 x}+20.344=-15.838 \cdot \mathrm{e}^{-0.291 x}-15.838 \cdot \mathrm{e}^{-0.475 x}+15.838\\
&-20.344 \cdot e^{-0.076 x}-15.838 \cdot e^{-0.291 x} \cdot e^{-0.475 x} \cdot e^{-0.475 x} \cdot e^{-0.475 x} \cdot e^{-0.838 \cdot e^{-0.291 x}+20.344}=-15.838 \cdot e^{-0.475 x}+15.838\\
&-20.344 \cdot e^{-0.076 x}-15.838 \cdot e^{-0.291 x} \cdot e^{-0.475 x} \cdot e^{-0.475 x} \cdot e^{-0.475 x} \cdot e^{-0.291 x}+15.838 \cdot e^{-0.475 x}+20.344=15.838\\
&-20.344 \cdot \mathrm{e}^{-0.076 \mathrm{x}}-15.838 \cdot \mathrm{e}^{-0.291 \mathrm{x}} \cdot \mathrm{e}^{-0.475 \mathrm{x}}+15.838 \cdot \mathrm{e}^{-0.291 \mathrm{x}}+15.838 \cdot \mathrm{e}^{-0.475 \mathrm{x}}=-4.506\\
&-20.344 \cdot \mathrm{e}^{-0.076 \mathrm{x}}-15.838 \cdot \mathrm{e}^{-0.291 \mathrm{x}} \cdot \mathrm{e}^{-0.475 \mathrm{x}}+15.838 \cdot \mathrm{e}^{-0.291 \mathrm{x}}+15.838 \cdot \mathrm{e}^{-0.475 \mathrm{x}}+4.506=0\\
&\text{logarithmise everything:}\\
&-\log(20.344)\cdot (-0.076x)-\log(15.838)\cdot (-0.291x)\cdot (-0.475x)+\log(15.838)\cdot (-0.291x)+\log(15.838)\cdot (-0.475x)+\log(4.506)=0\\
&-3.013\cdot (-0.076x)-2.762\cdot (-0.291x)\cdot (-0.475x)+2.762\cdot (-0.291x)+2.762\cdot (-0.475x)+1.505=0\\
&0.229x-0.382x^2-0.804x-1.312x+1.505=0\\
&-0.382x^2-1.887x+1.505=0\\
&\text{divide by -0.382:}\\
&x^2+4.940x-3.940=0
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

Comment: Your calculator is probably just approximating these intersections numerically using some variant of Newton's method. Your equations are ugly ugly ugly, and I doubt you are going to be able to solve this algebraically.

Comment: I know :) Formatting is right now my least concern. So there is only Newton's method as possible way?

Comment: There must be something wrong here (or I am just silly). A polynomial of degree 2 can only have 2 zeroes, but you claim to have three intersections of your curves...

Comment: @PrudiiArca These are not polynomials. And I don't believe you could rewrite them as polynomials even using a variable substitution (certainly not of degree 2).

Comment: The last thing in the equations you wrote certainly is one. I have no idea, where this came from, but assuming it is the last step of solving your equations for $x$, there is clearly something wrong as you seem to want to have 3 solutions...